# how to image upload from server folders using php jquery

Tags: php, jquery, image, upload

Is there any chance to upload images from my server folders? i mean if we place browse button in forms it will take images from my desktop(example) or from my system. but i need to give an option to upload the images from my server folder only.

Comment: Upload to where? And of course you can always use a little server-side script to read the contents of an image folder, and deliver the files contained (maybe filtered in some way before) to the client to build a list for the user to select from.

Comment: i have  folder like images in my website. when ever user click on the form file input.. need to upload only files from images folder which is in my website.